# MYSQL command line SELECT INTO OUTFILE, LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO TABLE to CSV with html data in column

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv, wysiwyg

I have columns which are `WYSIWYG` when i use `SELECT INTO FILE` command to `CSV` data gets messed up when I open the data with excel is all over the place column `b` data in column `c` and so on and  I can't using `LOAD DATA INFILE`  command either.

If I remove all `html` it works but I need the html!

Anyone has done it before and how can i achieve this?

By the example found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

```
SELECT  'id', 'title', 'driving', 'transit', 'parking', 'summary', 
'description', 'is_active' UNION ALL SELECT title, driving, transit, 
parking, summary, description, status FROM MY_TABLE INTO OUTFILE 
'/var/lib/mysql-files/my_table.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY 
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Screen shoot data from `my_table.csv`
[image]

You can see id `column` 1 then bellow data belonging to one of driving, transit, parking or summary. then id 2 right after I think the issue is with new lines in WYSWYG columns I need to keep them iin the right column when I export to CSV.

Comment: a+b - + is an arithmetic expression in mysql does it make sense here? I don't know ,can't see the data - would you like to provide some?

Comment: @P.Salmon I've update the question with more relevant data and actual query

Comment: show a capture of your csv file in a text editor, not excel. or at least a revelant part with copy / past. and a sample of your datas. show the expected result.

Comment: @Eric  the expected result I need is that `id` column have only numbers not data from other field. do you know how one can export to CSV columns that contains html without messing  it up how would you do? give some example I can try?

Comment: Even at 300% magnification I cannot read the image., it would be helpful if you added sample data from my_table.

Comment: @P.Salmon the question is simple how do export table with column that contains html to CSV.  How would you do it? give some example if you are willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

CSV is not suitable at all for exporting HTML. Your text fields probably contain a comma or double quotes, which shifts all the data read after it. It's not just a display problem.

you can try to replace the comma sign, by htmlentitie ,  to avoid CSV breaking format.

assuming title and description are HTML...

```
SELECT id,
       replace (title,       ','  , '&comma;' ) as title, 
       replace (description, ','  , '&comma;' ) as description 
FROM your_table
```

but without real datas, it's hard to get a solution at your problem.

Comment: so far I've got my query FIELDS and LINES clauses  as so: `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;`  My best shot so is open the file an find and replace  e.g: `\"eyeCatching\"`  with ""eyeCatching"" then everything falls into place, But if you know how to get it done with a query is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had is that WYSWYG data is has html content with like so: `class="class"` and anchor tags like so: `<a href="anchor-link">anchor text</a>`
Here is my option to resolve the issue. it includes Headers:

```
 SELECT  'id', 'title', 'driving', 'transit', 'parking', 'summary','description','is_active'
 UNION ALL SELECT id, title, driving, transit, parking, summary, description, status 
 FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/data.csv' 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

With the query above it will add `\` before `"` in html class and `<a>` tags.

Open the file with an editor of your choice and string replace `\"` with `""`

And everything falls into place!